# How do I sum columns of certain rows of my dataset?

Tags: r, sum, row

I am trying to sum across columns using `colSums`. So I convert my data.frame into a matrix so that the values are numeric, but when I do so the values change.

Consider this data.frame for example-

```
 X1 X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8   X9  X10  X11 X12  X13  X14  X15  X16 X17 X18 X19 X20
 1 <NA>  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0    0    0    0    1   0   0   0   0   0   0
 2 <NA>  0   0 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   0 <NA>    0 <NA> <NA>   0   0   0   0   0   0
3    0  0 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    0   0    0 <NA>    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4    0  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0    0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5    0  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0    0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6 <NA>  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0    0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

(Sorry for the sloppy formatting)
Becomes this data.matrix:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22
1 NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1
2 NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA   1  NA   1  NA  NA   1   1   1   1   1   1
3  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA   1   1   1  NA   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
4  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   2   2   2   2   2   2
5  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   2   2   2   2   2   2
6 NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
dat=read.xlsx("data",1)
datat=t(CWA2.3)
df=data.frame(datat[c(9,12,15,18,21,24),])
dm=data.matrix(LaughCWA2.3)
dm
```

Sorry if I committed a faux pas; I am new to R and this is my first time posting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum across columns (i.e., one sum per row), then you want to use `rowSums`, not `colSums`. To remove those missing values from your output, set the option `na.rm` to `TRUE`.

```
rowSums(dm, na.rm=TRUE)
```

For more information about this function, please see its R documentation [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/colSums.html).

Welcome to StackOverflow and good luck with R! :-)